# Using FIND function in excel

Tags: excel, find

I have a date "2017-09-01 00:02:01". I need to use the FIND function to identify the first space in this date. The following function gave me an error on MS-excel but worked perfectly fine on google sheets.
=FIND(" ",C2)

Why?

I tried to split the date and time in the above mentioned value. In order to do that, I wanted to use the RIGHT and LEFT functions. To use these functions, I needed to use the space as a delimiter and so I tried identifying the position at which the space is using FIND function.

Comment: `=FIND(" ",C2)` this works fine to my excel. You can use search() function. What is your excel version? If O365 then could use `TEXTSPLIT()`.

Comment: thank you for your inputs. I'm using excel on MAC. Its version 16.68. Let me try what you have suggested.

Comment: Turns out the date wasn't stored as a string. I used   =TEXT(D4,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") to convert the date to string and then tried using the FIND function. It worked fine this time.